# A TextView's String is being set wrong - How can I fix it?

Tags: java, android

I have been working with android studio for about five weeks. In this time, I have learned how to set a TextView's string and set a string variable containing that string. I have been trying to make an app game for android devices, and have encountered a problem whilst changing some code.

The textView myText is supposed to specify a coloured button to press, but when I press the start button in the android emulator, the randomly generated text and button never correlate with each other, even though I have a series of if statements to make sure that they do.

for some reason when I run the code the first colour button is always the correct button, and then runs the method colourSwitch as it should if it is correct, but I do not know what the problem is regarding connecting the correct coloured button to the correct text. Oh, and I am connecting this activity with a losing game activity which is called when any wrong button is pressed. If you want the code for the other activity, I am happy to show.

Here is my xml file for the game activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/game_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.a2118667.red.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/indicatorText">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/Game_Start_Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.156" />

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="299dp"
        android:layout_height="301dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.505"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.88">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="1" />
    </GridLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/indicatorText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text=" "
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/startButton"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my Java file for the game activity.

```
    package com.example.a2118667.red;
//imports
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;

import static  com.example.a2118667.red.R.id.startButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final int[] cowbears = {0};
    final int[] cowbears2 = {0};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.indicatorText);

        final Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);

        final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        final Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);


        myButton.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((ViewGroup) myButton.getParent()).removeView(myButton);
                        colourSwitch();
                    }
                }
        );




        button4.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        myText.setText("cowBears rock");
                        // if button says yellow and button is yellow
                        if (cowbears[0] == 2 && cowbears2[0] <= 1 || cowbears[0] == 6 && cowbears2[0] <= 1) {
                            myText.setText("You did it, mommy!");
                        }
                        // if button says blue and button blue
                        if (cowbears[0] == 3 && cowbears2[0] == 2 || cowbears[0] == 7 && cowbears2[0] == 2) {
                            myText.setText("You did it, mommy!");
                        }
                        // if button says green and button green
                        if (cowbears[0] == 4 && cowbears2[0] == 3 || cowbears[0] == 8 && cowbears2[0] == 3) {
                            myText.setText("You did it, mommy!");
                        }
                        // if button says red and button red
                        if (cowbears[0] <= 1 && cowbears2[0] == 4 || cowbears[0] == 5 && cowbears2[0] == 4) {
                            myText.setText("You did it, mommy!");
                        }
                        String verify = myText.getText().toString();
                        if (verify.equals("cowBears rock")){
                            losedThegameBoi();
                        }

                        String check = myText.getText().toString();
                        if (check.equals("You did it, mommy!")) {
                            colourSwitch();
                        }

                    }
                }

        );

        button3.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        myText.setText("cowBears rock");
                        // if button says yellow and button is yellow
                        if (cowbears[0] == 3 && cowbears2[0] <= 1 || cowbears[0] == 8 && cowbears2[0] <= 1) {
                            myText.setText("You did it, mommy!");
                        }
                        // if button says blue and button blue
                        if (cowbears[0] == 4 && cowbears2[0] == 2 || cowbears[0] == 5 && cowbears2[0] == 2) {
                            myText.setText("You did it, mommy!");
                        }
                        // if button says green and button green
                        if (cowbears[0] <= 1 && cowbears2[0] == 3 || cowbears[0] == 6 && cowbears2[0] == 3) {
                            myText.setText("You did it, mommy!");
                        }
                        // if button says red and button red
                        if (cowbears[0] == 2 && cowbears2[0] == 4 || cowbears[0] == 7 && cowbears2[0] == 4) {
                            myText.setText("You did it, mommy!");
                        }
                        String verify = myText.getText().toString();
                        if (verify.equals("cowBears rock")){
                            losedThegameBoi();
                        }

                        String check = myText.getText().toString();
                        if (check.equals("You did it, mommy!")) {
                            colourSwitch();
                        }
                    }
                }
        );


        button2.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        myText.setText("cowBears rock");
                        // if button says yellow and button yellow
                        if (cowbears[0] == 4 && cowbears2[0] <= 1 || cowbears[0] == 7 && cowbears2[0] <= 1) {
                            myText.setText("You did it, mommy!");
                        }
                        // if button says blue and button blue
                        if (cowbears[0] <= 1 && cowbears2[0] == 2 || cowbears[0] == 8 && cowbears2[0] == 2) {
                            myText.setText("You did it, mommy!");
                        }
                        // if button says green and button green
                        if (cowbears[0] == 2 && cowbears2[0] == 3 || cowbears[0] == 5 && cowbears2[0] == 3) {
                            myText.setText("You did it, mommy!");
                        }
                        // if button says red and button red
                        if (cowbears[0] == 3 && cowbears2[0] == 4 || cowbears[0] == 6 && cowbears2[0] == 4) {
                            myText.setText("You did it, mommy!");
                        }
                        String verify = myText.getText().toString();
                        if (verify.equals("cowBears rock")){
                            losedThegameBoi();
                        }

                        String check = myText.getText().toString();
                        if (check.equals("You did it, mommy!")) {
                            colourSwitch();
                        }
                    }
                }
        );


        // onClick Listeners for buttons
        button1.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        //debugged

                        myText.setText("cowBears rock");
                        // if button says yellow and button yellow
                        if (cowbears[0] <= 1 && cowbears2[0] <= 1 || cowbears[0] == 5 && cowbears2[0] <= 1) {
                            myText.setText("You did it, mommy!");
                        }
                        // if button says blue and button blue
                        if (cowbears[0] == 2 && cowbears2[0] == 2 || cowbears[0] == 6 && cowbears2[0] == 2) {
                            myText.setText("You did it, mommy!");
                        }
                        // if button says green and button green
                        if (cowbears[0] == 3 && cowbears2[0] == 3 || cowbears[0] == 7 && cowbears2[0] == 3) {
                            myText.setText("You did it, mommy!");
                        }
                        // if button says red and button red
                        if (cowbears[0] == 4 && cowbears2[0] == 4 || cowbears[0] == 8 && cowbears2[0] == 4) {
                            myText.setText("You did it, mommy!");
                        }
                        String verify = myText.getText().toString();
                        if (verify.equals("cowBears rock")){
                            losedThegameBoi();

                        }

                        String check = myText.getText().toString();
                        if (check.equals("You did it, mommy!")) {
                            colourSwitch();
                        }

                    }
                }
        );

    }


    private void losedThegameBoi() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Loser_Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void colourSwitch() {
        final TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.indicatorText);

        final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        final Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

        final int[] cowBears = {0};
        final int[] cowBears2 = {0};

        final int[] cowbears = {0};
        final int[] cowbears2 = {0};


        //Random number generator for randomizing colour layout
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        //For generating what colour pattern to be displayed
        int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(9);
        myText.setText("Generated : " + randomInt);
        cowBears[0] = randomInt;
        cowbears[0] = randomInt;
        //Colour patterns based on what integer is generated
        //Random number generator for randomizing button click stuff
        Random randomGenerator2 = new Random();
        //For generating which text to be displayed
        int randomInt2 = randomGenerator2.nextInt(5);
        myText.setText("Generated : " + randomInt2);
        cowBears2[0] = randomInt2;
        cowbears2[0] = randomInt2;

        // if statements for the colour scheme
        if (cowBears[0] <= 1) {
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow);
            button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
            button3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
            button4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.download);
        }

        if (cowBears[0] == 2) {
            button4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow);
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
            button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
            button3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.download);
        }

        if (cowBears[0] == 3) {
            button3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow);
            button4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
            button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.download);
        }

        if (cowBears[0] == 4) {
            button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow);
            button3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
            button4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.download);
        }
        if (cowBears[0] == 5) {
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow);
            button3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
            button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
            button4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.download);
        }

        if (cowBears[0] == 6) {
            button4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow);
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
            button3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
            button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.download);
        }

        if (cowBears[0] == 7) {
            button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow);
            button4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
            button3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.download);
        }

        if (cowBears[0] == 8) {
            button3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow);
            button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
            button4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.download);
        }

        //Here we have the randomizing of the button text based on what integer is genetated for cowbears2
        if (cowBears2[0] <= 1) {
            myText.setText("yellow" + cowBears[0] + cowBears2[0]);
        }

        if (cowBears2[0] == 2) {
            myText.setText("Blue" + cowBears[0] + cowBears2[0]);
        }

        if (cowBears2[0] == 3) {
            myText.setText("Green" + cowBears[0] + cowBears2[0]);
        }

        if (cowBears2[0] == 4) {
            myText.setText("Red" + cowBears[0] + cowBears2[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone could figure out why my code behaves like this, that would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll works, but change the `final` statements for `private` (or `public`) statements and run the app again. The code seems ok to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. You see my cowbears, and cowBears integers were being randomized differently.

The cowBears, cowBears2, cowbears, and cowbears2 final integers must be declared directly above the onCreate method, as the upper case cowBear integers were being redeclared during a button press.